# How do I delete all image files with same album id?

Tags: c#, asp.net, file, sql-delete

I have a two tables, one with all the pictures (called billeder, its danish), that have foreign key (in my code called 'album') that tells witch album it belongs to, and then I have the one with albums, with the primary key (alb_id). So i can eval the pictures from an specific album.

I know how to delete a picture, both in the table and in the folder on the server. That works fine.

But I need to know how to delete all of the pictures in the folder at once.

I have this so far:

```
  SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connectionstring"].ToString());

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

    cmd.Connection = conn;


    cmd.CommandText = "DELETE FROM albums WHERE alb_id = @id";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);

    conn.Open();  // Open the connection
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();

    cmd.CommandText = "DELETE FROM billeder WHERE album = @id";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);

    conn.Open();  // Open the connection
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();
```

The code i have for deleting the file:

```
   File.Delete(Server.MapPath("../fotos/" + image));
```

Comment: `But i need to know how to delete all of the pictures in the folder at once`, Why? Delete them one by one...

Comment: That's not very user friendly for the one using my page :) I hope there is a solution,

Comment: @SeanCox - She is using parameterized SQL commands. SQL Injection should not be a worry. However, she should wrap her connection and command in `using` statements to prevent memory and performance issues.

Comment: Do you have the `id`s for the album's photos either in the file name, or in any of your db tables?

Comment: What is the table definition of `billeder`? Do you have image path, album id etc in it?

Comment: In billeder i have id, image path and album id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you have the image path in the `billeder` table you can query them before you delete the rows from the table:

```
cmd.CommandText = "select imagePath FROM billeder WHERE album = @id";
var result = cmd.ExecuteQuery();
```

Then loop over the result set deleting each image in turn:

```
foreach (var image in result) // assuming the result set is a list of strings
{
     File.Delete(Server.MapPath("../fotos/" + image));
}
```

A better solution would be to put the images into a folder per album (either use the album id or, better still a guid, as the name of the folder, then you can delete the folder with a single call.

Comment: Thanks, i think i'll make folders, but this is still good to know i think. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT :** Update my answer on how to create directory per album and delete it, note : albumId must be unique

create directory per album

```
var path = Server.MapPath("../fotos/") + albumId;

CreateDirectory(path);
```

delete the album directory

```
Directory.Delete(path , true);
```

Comment: Are you sure that the folder contains **only** the files of that album?

Comment: from the O,P "But i need to know how to delete all of the pictures in the folder at once."

Comment: But I still read it as *"delete all of the pictures (of that album) in the folder at once"*

Comment: @Shachaf.Gortler , like @L.B says, OP wants to delete all pics for the particular album id in question. It's in the title itself! `How do I delete all image files with same album id?`.

Comment: The folder contains ALL of the pictures, i can see now that it's kinda the problem. So i should make a folder for every album? How do i make that in code, when i make a new album in the database?

Comment: You can either create new folders with the unique album `id` as the name of the folder. Then when you are deleting the records, just delete the folder with same `id`. Alternately, you can also have the association of images to album in a relationship table, with image name, path etc, and loop through that to delete just the specific image files in a single folder. Finally, you can also suffix or prefix the images with the album id and in your code, delete only the images that have the in the name (this could be error prone)

Comment: Update my answer on how to create directory per album and delete it

Comment: Okay, so that deletes the specific album folder, but how do i create it, like when i create a new album?

Comment: Maybe i should start a whole new question about that.

Comment: CreateDirectory function, create the album directory with the name of it as the album id under fotos directory

Comment: @CarolineOlivia `Maybe i should start a whole new question about that` No, Just take a step back and think about your problem....

Comment: How do i set the id for the album in this code?        `Directory.CreateDirectory("c:\\testDir1")`

Comment: I dont under stand the question , could you please elaborate